# Glassfish logging to file

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

I configured glassfish to write logs to specified folder, set file rotation limit and maximum history files. And everything works great, log files are in specified folder, rotated properly. But now i found there's still a log file in default location: /domain1/log/server.log
and it's not rotated ever and it's allready a 2GB size. 
How do i disable writing to this file? My log handler is set to java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

Comment: How did you configure GlassFish?

Comment: the problem was in a 3rd party library that uses it's own logging, so it was out of glassfish control